Feasibility of a MUST statement in YANG
I would like to ask for a favor.
I have the following YANG leafs:
I would like to make a MUST statement which allows to configure B = 1 only when the same value of G and H are configured together across different values of D.
`    container A {
        leaf B {
            type Boolean;
        }
        container C {
            key leaf D
            container E {
                key leaf F
                leaf G
                leaf H
            }
        }
    }`

For example:
It is possible to configure B = 1 in the below case:



D = D1
G
H




F = F1
G1
H2


F = F2
G15
H10






D = D2
G
H




F = F1
G15
H10


F = F2
G1
H2



while, it is impossible to configure B = 1 in the below case:



D = D1
G
H




F = F1
G1
H2


F = F2
G15
H10






D = D2
G
H




F = F1
G15
H2


F = F2
G1
H10



Is it possible to do it?
I studied about the usage of MUST statement from "RFC 7950: The YANG 1.1 Data Modeling Language (rfc-editor.org)", but I do not know whether the MUST I want to create is feasible or not.
